# How to get full stacktrace in SBT 0.10.0?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using SBT 0.10.0 to compile a combination of Java and Scala files. When I run the program through `sbt run` it returns a nonzero error but doesn't show me a stacktrace -- it simply fails silently with the cryptic message:

```
Nonzero exit code: 1
```

If I run the program through `scala` command line, it does show the stacktrace.

Is there any way I can get SBT to print out the entire stacktrace?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but did you try adding `logLevel := Level.Error` in your build.sbt.

Answer (score 15):

Execute `sbt` to get into the sbt shell, then try `run` followed by `last run`.

`last <command>` outputs everything that the command produced (all log levels, including [debug]) and stacktraces.

Answer (score 5):

`last run`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481702/scala-sbt-how-to-get-full-traceback/6483798#6483798),  is the way to go, but it can be annoying if you are doing something like running in a loop with `~ run` and just want to see your app's exceptions.  You can tell SBT to enable printing the stack traces automatically for a task like this:

```
traceLevel in run := 0
```

Further reference [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/Oubyb6LlZA8/6ihYrzRyTKMJ).

Answer (score 0):

In SBT 0.13.x, the stack trace's printed out so the question might've become irrelevant now.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1
$ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running MyApp
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.Exception: exception
java.lang.Exception: exception
    at MyApp$delayedInit$body.apply(Hello.scala:2)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at MyApp$.main(Hello.scala:1)
    at MyApp.main(Hello.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Jan 16, 2014 12:37:25 AM
```